# why is it deadlock?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just want add next date row. It is simple task, but it took 13 hours. Please help.

```
update m4 set
  m4.nday = m3.nday    
from [stock].dbo.logday m4
join (
    select
        stockcode,
        logdate,
        (
            select logdate from [stock].dbo.Logday d2 
            where d2.logdate >  d1.logDate and stockcode= d1.stockCode 
            order by logdate asc 
            offset 0 rows fetch next 1 rows only
        ) nday
    from stock.dbo.logday d1 
) m3
on m4.stockcode = m3.stockcode and m4.logdate = m3.logdate
```

Comment: Its not possible to assist without knowing more about your database design. Please provide the execution plan and further details of the table structures, indexes and number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt to simply your query without the schema and sample data (so it is not tested).

```
update m4
set m4.nday = 
(
select min(m3.logdate)
from [stock].dbo.logday m3
where m3.stockcode = m4.stockcode
and m3.logdate > m4.logdate
)
from [stock].dbo.logday m4
```